# Reading contents of different webpages and adding then together to put into another URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm not advanced at python but its the best coding language I know. I'm doing this challenge that has 5 URLS which change contents every 10 seconds. They each contain part of a code. There is also a validation link which checks the urls I have clicked and checks if it the right code, if it is it will give me a code. So to solve this I'm writing a script that will get all the contents of the 5 URLs and concatenate them together and paste it in the URL of the validation link which will then give me a code which I need.

Here's my code

```
import urllib.request

fp1 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt1?verify=Gl7fPRYxQvgBdbmhMo8vkA%3D%3D")
mybytes1 = fp1.read()
fp1.close()

fp2 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt2?verify=Gl7fPRYxQvgBdbmhMo8vkA%3D%3D")
mybytes2 = fp2.read()
fp2.close()

fp3 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt3?verify=Gl7fPRYxQvgBdbmhMo8vkA%3D%3D")
mybytes3 = fp3.read()
fp3.close()

fp4 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt4?verify=Gl7fPRYxQvgBdbmhMo8vkA%3D%3D")
mybytes4 = fp4.read()
fp4.close()

fp5 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt5?verify=Gl7fPRYxQvgBdbmhMo8vkA%3D%3D")
mybytes5 = fp5.read()
fp5.close()

fp6 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/get-flag?verify=Gl7fPRYxQvgBdbmhMo8vkA%3D%3D&string=" + mybytes1 + mybytes2 + mybytes3 + mybytes4 + mybytes5)
mybytes6 = fp6.read()
fp6.close()

print(mybytes6)
```

However I am getting an error which I don't understand.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
_context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sarvesh/Documents/scriptdis.py", line 3, in <module>
fp1 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt1?verify=Gl7fPRYxQvgBdbmhMo8vkA%3D%3D")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
'_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

You are trying to open a website without a valid certificate. If you trust the website, then you need to create an uncertified context or urllib will throw the error you are seeing.

```
import ssl

# This restores the same behavior as before.
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
fp1 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt1?verify=Gl7fPRYxQvgBdbmhMo8vkA%3D%3D", context=context)
```